# Using both yticks and ylim in a logarithmic pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some trouble using both `ylim` and `yticks` in a log scale pyplot. See the output of the following piece of code:

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3))
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
y = np.exp(-5*x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c=blue, markersize=4)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.yticks([10**-1, 1/np.e, 10**0], [r'$10^{-1}$', r'$1/e$', r'$10^0$'])
plt.ylim(10**-1,10**0)
```

This gives

[image]

Clearly there are more ticks than the ones I specified. If I don't use `ylim` or `yscale` however, the correct 3 ticks show up. Using `semilogy` results in the same issue. Has anyone encountered this before, and does anyone know a workaround? This is for matplotlib 3.1, but it also happened in 3.0 (from which I just upgraded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see are essentially the minor tick labels. The reason I think they appear after setting the limits is because you are kind of zooming in within a small range. A straightforward workaround is to hide the minor tick labels. To access them, I use the axis object `ax`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3)) # <--- Define an axis object
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
y = np.exp(-5*x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c='blue', markersize=4)
plt.yscale('log')

plt.ylim(10**-1,10**0)
plt.setp(ax.get_yminorticklabels(), visible=False) # <--- Hide the minors
plt.yticks([10**-1, 1/np.e, 10**0], [r'$10^{-1}$', r'$1/e$', r'$10^0$']);
```

[image]